# Get pixel color in Android

Tags: android

How to get the color at fixed pixels:

this is my code

```
public static void getColor(Bitmap btm,Activity act){
    int w = 300;
    int h = 500;
    btm=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(btm, w,h, true);

    color1= btm.getPixel(30, 50);
    color2= btm.getPixel(50, 70);

}
```

Comment: Hiw do you retrieve Bitmap?

Comment: I dont know what you mean but I read Bitmap in other activity like that 

        Bitmap  btm= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                R.drawable.colors);

and handle the colors here in the method .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. I've used it to get the predominant color of an image.

```
public static int getDominantColor(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 1, 1, true);
    final int color = newBitmap.getPixel(0, 0);
    newBitmap.recycle();
    return color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the method that you have shared, its the way you are generating the bitmap and passing it to this function that has different sizes on different devices.

Just because you are scaling the device to a definite size does not mean that all pixels will have the same color for different screen sizes. This problem cannot be fixed by reading color from bitmap, so you have to explain the actual purpose, so we can solve it with different techniques.

Comment: My purpose is to get all the app layout and controls to  have the same colors its like a theme for the whole app and I will use it in other apps too.

Comment: For this purpose, taking screenshot and reading the pixel colour is the most inefficient option, is there a reason why you have decided to use this method? Have you considered using any other approach?

Comment: Also, to change the theme why do you have to read the colour?

Comment: I am ok with any other approach but I have to use this way because there is more than app must have the same style like buttons ,edit texts , and other controls , so the designer gave me the image and I extract the colors. to be more specified it's like a lib file i use it different apps